# How to set up one unit test that is skipped if another one fails?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

Is there a way in xUnit.net to make a unit test dependent on another so that it is **skipped** if the other one fails?

*Note: This is not a question about shared fixtures between tests or making tests coupled to each other etc. I avoid that.*

## Example

```
Given:     Unit tests OuterTest and InnerTest
Condition: If OuterTest is dependent on InnerTest and InnerTest fails
Result:    OuterTest is skipped (ideally with an explanation)
```

## Rationale

This is coming up as part of unit testing serialization, but I can think of other use cases as well. I have a type Outer that takes a dependency of type Inner where Inner is serialized as part of the serialization of Outer. I have a serialization unit test for type Inner, and if that fails I know that the serialization unit test for Outer will fail due to nesting.

The types look sort of like this:

```
[Serializable]
class Inner {}

[Serializable]
class Outer {
 
    public Outer(Inner inner) {
        Inner = inner;
    }

    [Serializable]
    Inner Inner { get; }
}
```

- I really don't want to use a Stub for Inner in the unit test for Outer because that forces me to introduce an interface for Inner and clutter up a hierarchy where only a single concrete implementation of these types are necessary. It also forces me to create a custom serializer for the stub which sounds like more trouble than the benefit.
- **Given that it is difficult to create a stub for the inner class, the following is my argument: I don't want both tests to fail because that makes it difficult to find the root cause of the failure. I think it is better if the unit test for Outer is skipped with a warning of the dependency failure.**

## Questions

I have not found any information on this use case after searching for a while, therefore I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to create tests that are running conditionally based on the result of other unit tests in xUnit.net?
2. Is this a bad request in any way or a code smell, and if so, why?

Comment: This is probably a bad idea. You want a test to test as small a thing as possible, and not be affected by the surrounding environment. If one change makes two unit tests break then either you introduced 2 problems, or you have too broad/brittle tests.

Comment: If they're dependent on each other, *they aren't unit tests*.

Comment: These objections are certainly the first thing that comes to mind, but on the contrary this was actually proposed as a method to *make them unit tests*. Given that the inner test succeeded the outer test would actually just test the outer unit. (Without having to change to code too much to conform with regular unit testing with interfaces and stubs, quite a lot of work in this situation)

Comment: Try to change the title, it invites comments that aren't about your specific question. I think it's a reasonable request. For instance, if you know a component only runs reliably on a system with a fine-grained clock, and it take a while to check that, make all its test cases dependent on a special test case.

Answer (score -2):

You don't want to do that. If you have something that breaks multiple tests, then you want your tests to showcase all the ways that one problem can effect the entire system.

What you should do in your case is to have two strands of tests that run through serializing your `Outer` class. One, with the objects as they exist, and the other using a mock of your `Inner` class.

There is a strong argument that the situation without the mocked `Inner` class could be considered an "integration" test, however, because it is just using the objects as they exist, I would think this is a bit of a grey area.

Having a test where `Outer` can't serialize because `Inner` can't is still something very important to know about by looking at the results of your unit tests.

Comment: Well, this goes against the two points I mentioned in the question. 1. I don't have an interface for Inner, which makes it difficult to mock. I could introduce this just for unit testing, but I don't find that very satisfactory. It even has a very negative impact on the performance of the serialization. 2. I don't think it is correct that it gives more information that the Outer unit test is failing in this case. IMO it is better to skip the Outer unit test with a warning, which gives me a quick feedback stating that the problem is with the Inner type. When that is fixed I can turn to Outer.

Comment: Yes, but this answers your second question: "Is this a bad request or a code smell. If so, why?"

Comment: The problem with answering about mocking the `Inner` class (and I'm not advocating making an interface for it, the mock will be a derived type), is that you don't explain why that class is occasionally, or all the time, unable to serialize. The mock should hopefully be able to get around that problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering the "why" part :) I'm just not sure I'm convinced by the argument in this particular case. I'm usually in favor of creating stubs/mocks, but here I have an Inner type that is very difficult to mock. It is sealed (because, reasons...) and I don't want to introduce an interface because the serializer I'm using is creating overhead for interface types (both stream size and time overhead).

Comment: I've updated the question with a clarification: Given that it is difficult to create a stub for the inner class, the following is my argument: I don't want both tests to fail because that makes it difficult to find the root cause of the failure. I think it is better if the unit test for Outer is skipped with a warning of the dependency failure.